# Counting via For Loops

Tags: c++

I need to use a For Loop to display all numbers from the input value down to 1.

I figured out the code to do the opposite of the question which is from 1 to input value but am confused if i should lower or increase the increment.

```
    for (i = 1; i <= userChoice; i++)
    {
        cout << "Loop 1:" << endl;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure you want i=1 to be your starting position? the 1st member of an array is array[0].

Comment: We haven't talked about arrays in our class yet. My prof said to have i = 1 for this program.

Comment: @MantejSokhi There's no array involved in your code at all??

Comment: If you can do from value to 1 then you should also do 1 to value.
And if you are confused about the increment/decrement then you should read about it. This increment/decrement is basic of for loop.

Comment: Um, guys, he never said he had an array. He said he needed it to display numbers. Was there an edit I missed? Why are we discussing arrays when the OP didn't mention them at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may increment counter

```
for (int i = 0; i < userChoice; ++i)
{
    std::cout << userChoice - i << std::endl;
}
```

or decrement it

```
for (int i = userChoice; i != 0; --i)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/rLr6XT)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to write the numbers in descending order.

```
for (i = userChoice; i >= 1; i--)
{
    cout << "Loop 1:" << endl;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```